# Prove that $|e^{z^2}|\le e^{|z|^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help proving that $|e^{z^2}|\le e^{|z|^2}$, where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hint: Use the power series: $|\exp(z^2)|=|\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^{2n}}{n!}|\leq$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $|e^z| = |e^x|$ , for any complex number $z=x+iy$.

Here is more details :

\begin{equation} |e^{z^2}| = |e^{x^2 - y^2}| = e^{x^2 - y^2} \leq e^{x^2 + y^2} = e^{|z|^2} \end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for any $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$, we have that
$$|e^{z}| = |e^{x+iy}| = |e^{x}|\cdot |e^{iy}|=e^x\cdot 1\leq e^{|x|}\leq e^{|z|}.$$